# Нужна ли запятая в этой пословице?

Tags: запятые

Пословица: Куй железо пока оно горячо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед *пока* запятая ставится, т. к. *пока оно горячо* — придаточное предложение

Comment: А если так?  Куй железо(,) пока горячо. Нужна запятая и как это объяснить?

Comment: Запятая все равно нужна и по той же причине. Да, подледащего во второй части нет, но подразумевается его присутствие. Перед *пока* не ставится запятая (если это союз), только если *пока* является частью устойчивых сочетаний

Comment: Спасибо за  ответ (второе предложение неполное). А вы знаете такие сочетания?

Comment: Вообще-то не знаю. Но я знал, что запятая точно ставится в Вашем примере, и объяснил как смог. Можете рассказать?

Comment: Нет, у меня не получилось придумать. А предложение не мое, именно так звучит пословица. https://phraseology.academic.ru/5449/Ковать_железо%2C_пока_горячо